# Recreating "Hosted Build Controller"

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Apologies if this is a dumb question...

I've been playing around on our TFS server - learning by trial-and-error. For our simple development needs, I think using a "Hosted Build Controller" should be just fine.

However, I've deleted, unregistered and re-created the Controller and Agent several times (Build folder is at 6 by now).

So how do I reset everything without breaking TFS, which is already live and running? Is the "Default Controller" inherently the same as a "Hosted Controller"? If not, how do I create a "Hosted Controller"? Finally, is there a way to start from one a again with the Build Agent Numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "default Controller" is the same as the "hosted controller", I think 'hosted' is the opposite of using one of MS's online ones.

It's not recommended to run a build controller on the same box as TFS itself, if you're doing that consider setting up another box using that for your builds. You can't share build controllers between collections so you're going to have to set up separate boxes at some point anyway. I wouldn't worry about the build number folder. To reset the build service, controller and any agents on a host via the "TFS Admin Console > Build Config", disable/delete the agents, controller and stop and unregister the service etc.

Comment: OK, thanks - I can always make my ClickOnce deployment server a controller/agent box